# Jquery определить текстовые тэги

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как в jquery можно наиболее оптимально отыскать все элементы с текстом и добавить к ним класс:
К примеру есть элементы

```
 <span>888888</span> <p>2342</p> <div>цукцук</div> <a
 href="#">888234234888</a>
```

Как их выборку произвести?
А элементы без содержания проигнорировать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно использовать селекторы [:not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) и [:has](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), [:empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

```
:not(:has(*),:empty)
```

В данном случае будут выбираться элементы, внутри которых нет других элементов.

Пример

```js
console.log($('#container :not(:has(*),:empty)').map(function(el) {
  return this.innerHTML;
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <span>888888</span> 
  <p>2342</p>
  <div>цукцук</div> <a href="#">888234234888</a>
  <div><span></span>
    sdds<span>cc</span>
  </div>
  <p>sdsdsd<i></i>
    <span>sdsd</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: ваш ответ не удовлетворяет условию "без содержания"...

Comment: @VenZell, да, пропустил этот момент, обновил ответ

Comment: не забудьте первую строчку тоже обновить, а так плюс :)

Comment: @VenZell, готово :-)

Answer (score 1):

в jquery есть селектор :empty, который выбирает элементы без содержимого и вложенных тегов
[http://jquery.page2page.ru/](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)

Чтобы выбрать не пустые можено сделать так

```
$(':not(:empty)').addClass('filled');
```

Comment: Мне не нужны пустые элементы, а только заполненые, да и этот тэг включает в себя внутренние элементы а мне нужен только текст

Comment: В этом случае он вешает на все тэги вообще класс, а не на текстовые блоки

Comment: @SdafsFasafs, что вы понимаете под _текстовыми блоками_?

Comment: то что я написал изначально, блоки или тэги имеющие во вложении только текст

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('#container *').contents().filter(function() {
   return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.data)
 }).parent().addClass('red')
```

```css
 .red {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   background-color: #FF0000;
   display: inline-block;
   border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <span>888888</span>
  <p>2342</p>
  <div>цукцук</div> <a href="#">888234234888</a>
  <div><span></span>
    sdds
    <span>cc</span>
  </div>
  <p>sdsdsd<i></i>
    <span>sdsd</span>
  </p>
</div>
```